# Bash script wont match on regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have the following bash script which should be producing the output TEST

```
#!/bin/bash

test="TEST:THING - OBJECT_X"
if [[ $test =~ ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[A-Z\s\-_]+$ ]]; then
      echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

In my regex tester the regular expression seems to be matching and capturing on the first and second groups:

https://regex101.com/r/kR1jM7/1

Any idea whats causing this?

Comment: Also, the tester is configured for PCRE, but bash uses ERE.

Comment: The colon doesn't need to be escaped; `\:` is the same as `:`.

Comment: I'd also strongly consider using `[:upper:]` in place of `A-Z`, `[:digit:]` in place of `0-9`, or `[:alnum:]` in place of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. These are much more likely to behave correctly in systems with other languages/locales enabled.

Comment: `[[ $test =~ ^([^:]+) ]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\s` is a PCRE construct not meaningful inside of ERE. Use `[:space:]` instead. Also, instead of escaping the dash as `\-`, move the `-` to the very end of the character set definition.

The following works:

```
[[ $test =~ ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+):([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[A-Z[:space:]_-]+$ ]]
```

That said, for compatibility with a wider range of bash releases, move the regex into a variable:

```
re='^([a-zA-Z0-9]+):([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[A-Z[:space:]_-]+$'
[[ $test =~ $re ]]
```

---

To use POSIX character classes more aggressively (and thus make your code more likely to work correctly across languages and locales), also consider:

```
re='^([[:alnum:]]+):([[:alnum:]]+)[[:upper:][:space:]_-]+$'
```

Comment: Very interesting about the PCRE vs ERE concept. I wasn't aware there were different flavors of regular expressions that varied so differently. and your answer does indeed work :)

Comment: (PCRE mandates a bunch of extensions, some of which aren't possible to implement without backtracking, making PCRE potentially much, much slower than conventional regular expression forms).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I need to do more research on this. Foolish of me to assume different languages would use the same regex format.